# Most efficient way to solve an adjacent element problem in vanilla js + html?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

This is the problem:

Create a 10x10 grid using html, vanilla javascript, and css.

When a square on that grid is clicked, change the background color of the adjacent squares (the one on top, to the left, etc) to yellow.

I was able to solve this problem, but I don't think it's efficient - My html is only one line:

```
<table id="grid"></table>
```

And I used javascript to manually populate the table with a bunch of cells/squares. I gave each cell an two attributes `data-row` and `data-col` to store where the cell is located. Then on click I'm doing something like this:

```
  var row = this.getAttribute('data-row');
  var col = this.getAttribute('data-col');

  ...

  //if not on the top most row, retrieve square above
  if(row>0){
      let sel = "td[data-row='"+(row-1)+"'][data-col='"+col+"']";
      let elem = document.querySelector(sel);
      elem.classList.toggle('yellow');
  }

  ...

  //3 more if blocks like the one above to find the bottom, left and right squares
```

Is there a more efficient or concise way of doing this? Thank you for your responses in advance! It's appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider calling the `querySelector` regardless, and then checking whether an element was selected, rather than having different `if (row > 0) ...` blocks before. For example:

```
tryChange(-1, 0);
tryChange(1, 0);
tryChange(0, -1);
tryChange(0, 1);
function tryChange(xDiff, yDiff) {
  const sel = "td[data-row='"+(row + xDiff)+"'][data-col='"+(col + yDiff)+"']";
  const elem = document.querySelector(sel);
  if (elem) {
    elem.classList.toggle('yellow');
  }
}
```

The `if (elem)` test will fail if no element was selected.

Comment: Nice! Yeah that made it a lot less chunky. Thanks :) nextsibling() or parent() aren't really useful in this scenario, correct?

Comment: They *could* be used to avoid using the `data-` attributes, but using `data-` attributes makes the JS code a lot more DRY. I'd prefer the current method.

Answer (score 0):

The way the desired outcome is stated makes me think the cell being clicked should **not** become yellow and the question is asking you to  process the [Moore neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) of a cell.

One approach to achieve this, which I've used in a game in the past, is to hold an array of the grid cells' DOM elements (a small "shadow DOM" if you will) in JavaScript and iterate around a clicked cell in the array to locate neighbors.

If a working example is of interest:

```js
"use strict";

// iterate through the Moore neighbors of a cell
// ( in a 2D rectangular array)

function iter8( r, c, cellArray, callback) {
    r=+r; // convert row and column string arguments to number
    c=+c;

    const 
        maxRow = cellArray.length -1,
        maxCol = cellArray[0].length -1,
        r0 = r ? r-1 : 0,
        r1 = r < maxRow ? r+1 : maxRow,
        c0 = c ? c-1 : 0,
        c1 = c < maxCol? c+1 : maxCol
    ;
    for( var row = r0; row <= r1; ++ row) {
        for( var col = c0; col <= c1; ++ col) {
            if( ! (row == r && col == c)) {
                callback( cellArray[row][col], row, col, cellArray);
            }
        }
    }
}

//  *******   Test Code Follows  *********

const div = document.getElementById("board");
const array = [];
for( var r = 0; r < 10; ++r) {
    array.push([]);
    for( var c = 0; c < 10; ++c) {
        var cell = document.createElement( "SPAN");
        cell.className = "cell";
        cell.dataset["row"] = r;
        cell.dataset["col"] = c;
        cell.textContent = "(" + r + "," + c + ")";
        array[ r].push( cell);
        div.appendChild( cell);
    }
    div.appendChild( document.createElement("BR"));
}
div.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let cell = event.target;
    if( cell.classList.contains("cell")) {
         iter8( cell.dataset.row, cell.dataset.col, array, 
             neighbor => neighbor.classList.contains("yellow") || neighbor.classList.add("yellow")
         );
    }
}, false);
```

```css
.div {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: default;
}
.cell.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this sample code! :) I didn't know what Moore neighborhood was, but it helps giving this thing a name. For the context of this question, its essentially moore neighborhood but without the diagonally adjacent cells. Unfortunately this is my first question on here, so I can't upvote or mark multiple questions as correct :/